# splitting text based on whitespace

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, split

```
            No time. Not today.
                (slides in last bullets)
            Ten, eleven, twelve... or bust.
                (chambers a shell into each
                 gun, looks up)
            Right here!

The cab SCREECHES to a stop on the shoulder of the highest
FREEWAY in a massive INTERCHANGE of freeways. Dopinder halts
the meter and hands Deadpool his CARD.
```

My goal is to parse the above text such that the dialogue is separated from the description. There are multiple instances of this in my file. The output should be two separate strings x and y, where:
x = "No time. Not Today...Right Here!" and y = "The cab SCREECHES...his CARD".

How can I achieve this using Regular Expression matching? Or is there a better way to solve this? I'm using python.

Comment: Try beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)** to parse the content from the webpage.
it is easier to extract content based on the required tag. it is not a good idea to parse HTML using regex.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<b>                          DEADPOOL (CONT'D) </b>                Little help?

    The cabbie grabs Deadpool's hand and pulls him through to the
    front. Deadpool's head rests upside down on the bench seat
    as he maneuvers his legs through. The cabbie turns the
    helping hand into a HANDSHAKE, then turns down the Juice.

<b>                            CABBIE </b>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.text)
```

**Output:**

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I have updated my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You seems mistook the string "little Help?" for "A little Help?". And `x, y` what you want to extract are strings separated by `newlines`(`\n\n`) in the same block .

You can try this,

```
ss="""<b>                          DEADPOOL (CONT'D) </b>                Little help?

The cabbie grabs Deadpool's hand and pulls him through to the
front. Deadpool's head rests upside down on the bench seat
as he maneuvers his legs through. The cabbie turns the
helping hand into a HANDSHAKE, then turns down the Juice.

<b>                            CABBIE </b>"""
import re
regx=re.compile(r'(?s)(?<=\>)[^<>]*(?=\<)')
lst=[m.strip() for m in regx.findall(ss)]
xy=[m.strip() for m in re.split(r'\n{2}',lst[1])]
for i in xy: print(i+"\n")     # x=xy[0], y=xy[1]
```

Output is,

```
Little help?
The cabbie grabs Deadpool's hand and pulls him through to the
front. Deadpool's head rests upside down on the bench seat
as he maneuvers his legs through. The cabbie turns the
helping hand into a HANDSHAKE, then turns down the Juice.
```

**Edited** for the input of your 2nd additional question.

```
ss="""copy&paste_Your_Input_string_Here"""
xy=[m.strip() for m in re.split(r'\n{2}',ss)]
for i in xy: print(i +"\n")     # x=xy[0], y=xy[1]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but my question is a bit different than what you understood. I have updated the question. Thanks again!

Comment: I edited my answer for your additional 2nd question. Please try it again, thanks:-)